# How to access and update DOM element in angular 4

Tags: angular

In My HTML I have `addReply` function which lies within `ngFor`, beneath it lies a span with textarea I want to show(change css) that textarea on click when `addReply` is triggered that when user click on reply.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="row">


    <div class="col-lg-12" *ngFor="let commentData of commentsData; let i = index">

      <div style="padding:10px;border-bottom:1px solid #A4A4A5;
       border-radius:5px;background-color:#F4F4F4;
        font-weight:normal;width:500px;">

        <img style="border-radius:50%;width:30px;height:30px;"src="{{commentData.comment_posted_by_image}}">

        <span>{{commentData.text}}</span>
        <br>
        <span style="margin-left:10%;color:#BDC0C2">{{commentData.comment_posted_by}}</span>
        <span style="margin-left:10%;cursor:pointer">
          <a (click)="addReply($event, commentData.id)" style="color:#30B7EF;">reply</a>
        </span>
        <span style="display: none" >
          <textarea style="width:50%" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </span>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef,  ViewChild, Renderer2  } from '@angular/core';
import { CommentsDataService} from "../../services/comments/comments-data.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-comments',
  templateUrl: './list-comments.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-comments.component.css']
})
export class ListCommentsComponent implements OnInit {
  commentsData;
  getComments;
  postId;
  commentId = 0;
  showReplyTextarea:boolean=false;
  @ViewChild('replyTextarea') input;

  addReply(event, commentId);
  addReply(event, commentId)
  {
   console.log(event, commentId);


  }
  constructor(private commentsDataService:CommentsDataService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {


    this.commentsData = this.commentsDataService.getComments(this.postId);
     console.log( this.commentsData)
  }

}
```

My element id will also be going to be combination of string and `commentData.id`.
I don't know how to do that too.

Answer (score 0):

You could set an id on the `span`.

```
<span id={{commentData.id}} style="display: none">
    <textarea style="width:50%" class="form-control"></textarea>
</span>
```

then in your `addReply` function set the `span` with that id to remove the display property so that it will show.

```
addReply(event, commentId){
   var textarea = document.getElementById(commentId);
   textarea.style.removeProperty('display');

   ... 
}
```

Comment: Got this error: ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '1' is not a valid selector. My id id 1.

Comment: Sorry forgot the pound sign in the querySelector. replace with this `('#' + commentId)`

Comment: Make sure no other elements make use of the ids you will be using to create the spans

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error. Any idea? Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'. Thanks.

Comment: Try getElementById instead of querySelector? That may be giving you that issue. I updated my code

Answer (score 0):

> Conditional styling using [NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass). You dont need to query the DOM tree to do this.

How about adding a conditional styling for your span

Syntax

```
<some-element [ngClass]="{'class1 class2 class3' : true}">...</some-element>
```

**Example**

```
<span [ngClass]="{'SomeClass': isAddReplyClicked,
                  'SomeClass2': !isAddReplyClicked }">
    <textarea style="width:50%" class="form-control"></textarea>
</span>
```

Model Example

```
[ngClass]="{'NoDisplayStyle': isAddReplyClicked }"
```

**Component**

```
isAddReplyClicked: boolean;

addReply(event, commentId){
 isAddReplyClicked = true;
}
```

*This way you could Test your logic too.*